# .Net Application Insights - Telemetry Client inside Processor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure-application-insights

I have a telemetry processor that captures some metrics based on requests and dependencies. I need this processor to have an instance of `TelemetryClient` so it can log the metric aggregation.

but when I try to

```
services.AddSingleton<Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.ITelemetryProcessorFactory>(builder =>
{
     var svc = builder.GetRequiredService<TelemetryClient>(); //loop here!
     return new MyCustomProcessor(svc);
});
```

I get into an infinite loop! (not `StackOverflowException`)

Can anyone point out what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add telemetry processor like this:

```cs
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryProcessor<MyCustomProcessor>();
```